# How to add a polyfill to nuxt 2.0?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-edge

In Nuxt `1.4.2`, I had the following in my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
build: {
  vendor: ['babel-polyfill'],
  babel: {
    presets: [
      ['vue-app', {
        useBuiltIns: true,
        targets: { ie: 11, uglify: true },
      },
      ],
    ],
  },
},
```

It seems that all of this is broken in Nuxt `2.0`. At a minimum I'm looking to polyfill enough to get IE 11 working. Here's what I've tried:

### Using vendor as I used to

Removing `build.babel` allowed the build process to work:

```
build: {
  vendor: ['babel-polyfill'],
},
```

But I *think* `build.vendor` is just ignored now, so this seems to do nothing.

### Using polyfill.io

I tried adding:

```
script: [
  { src: 'https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js' },
],
```

to my `head`, along with:

```
render: {
  resourceHints: false,
},
```

to disable the `preload` hints (I'm unsure if this matters). This results in a page which looks correct - `polyfill.min.js` is loaded before all other scripts. Somehow, when I test on ie11, `Object.entries` is undefined and the page explodes.

Comment: Try to remove babel from build config at all. It should work automatically

Comment: @Aldarund thanks - I tried that as well. I can see (via build -a) that `core-js` is included, but I still see the same errors when testing. I wonder if `core-js` just isn't being hoisted properly in the build. But even if that were true, I don't understand why `polyfill.io` would fail.

Comment: Can't you just require the polyfil in a plugin?

Comment: @Imre_G I believe the polyfill is actually being included, and it works fine in a simple app. Once packages are included (in my case @nuxtjs/apollo), then it seems to break. When I have an update from the nuxt devs, I'll post my findings here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to upgrade to nuxt `2.2.0`, and get my app working on IE 11 with the necessary polyfills. Your experience may differ, depending on which packages you have installed.

**Step 1**

Remove `build.vendor` and `build.babel` from `nuxt.config.js`.

`build.vendor` is deprecated. I tried to tweak `build.babel`, as the [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#babel) indicate it defaults to using `vue-app`. I think it's actually using [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env). This, along with other tools, depends on [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist), which has some rational [defaults](https://browserl.ist/?q=defaults). I didn't change my browserslist config, but you could by following their [docs](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist).

**Step 2**

Upgrade or replace any modules causing build issues. When I upgraded, `@nuxtjs/apollo` had a transpilation problem via one of its dependencies. This has since been [resolved](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/issues/162), however I ended up switching to `vue-apollo` + `apollo-boost` as it was a better fit for my project.

**Step 3**

Add polyfills for any extra features `core-js` doesn't provide, but that your target browsers need. You should be able to determine these based on any exceptions thrown in the console while testing on your targets.

I used [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io) by adding the following to `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
const features = [
  'fetch',
  'Object.entries',
  'IntersectionObserver',
].join('%2C');

head: {
  script: [
    { src: `https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=${features}`, body: true },
  ],
},
```

> **Note:** I've included `body: true` which moves the script out of the `head` section of your page. It will, however, be inserted **before** any of your application code.
>
> **Note:** `IntersectionObserver` is recommended for [link prefetching](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#prefetchlinks).

You can create a similar URL by using the [builder](https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder). Note that once you select a feature, the builder will automatically select `default`, which is (as far as I can tell) functionally equivalent to the polyfills that ship with `core-js`. Because `core-js` isn't currently optional (you're going to ship it anyway), it makes sense not to include the `default` set from `polyfill.io`.

For an in-depth discussion of polyfills and why `polyfill.io` is probably a good idea, see [this post](https://hackernoon.com/polyfills-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-or-maybe-a-bit-less-7c8de164e423). The short version is that it loads only the stuff the client actually needs based on the browser's UA.

Finally, you'll need to test your app to see which additional features (if any) are needed for successful execution in a given browser. You may need to repeat this process several times until all of the errors go away. Make sure to test on multiple pages, as not all of your page bundles will have the same requirements.

**Conclusion**

While some aspects of the above are application-specific, hopefully this can help move you in the right direction. The most important takeaway is that there's no one solution to this - you'll still need to test in your target browsers to verify that the code executes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Hopefully the core team adresses this soon

Comment: @Merc This is a high priority issue for me. As I learn more, I'll be sure to add it here.

Comment: @Merc I've added some improvements based on continued experimentation. Please read the latest version of step 3 in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

I tried all the above approaches and nothing at all worked. However, I found that I could get my code to work with IE11 by creating a plugin and adding it to nuxt.config.js as follows:

// nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/polyfills', mode: 'client' },
  ],
```

// plugins/polyfills.js

```
import 'core-js/fn/object/entries'
import 'core-js/fn/array/includes'
import 'core-js/fn/array/find'
import 'core-js/fn/array/from'
import 'core-js/es6/promise'
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign'
import 'core-js/es6/symbol'
import 'whatwg-fetch'
```

I removed any special babel config. That's all it took. I know this means my code will always run the polyfills, but there are no 3rd party dependencies (polyfill.io for example). You may edit the list of required polyfills as needed. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is the best solution, IMO. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the [nuxt-polyfill](https://github.com/Timkor/nuxt-polyfill) module.

- It supports **feature detection** *before loading any polyfill*
- Is compatible with [polyfill.io](http://polyfill.io) polyfills.
- Does not include the polyfills in default bundles.
- Lazy loads polyfills only if needed
- Delays Nuxt initialization if and only if polyfills are required.

```
npm install nuxt-polyfill
```

Add the module to your nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {

    // Configure polyfills:
    polyfill: {
        features: [
            /* 
                Feature without detect:

                Note: 
                  This is not recommended for most polyfills
                  because the polyfill will always be loaded, parsed and executed.
            */
            {
                require: 'url-polyfill' // NPM package or require path of file
            },

            /* 
                Feature with detect:

                Detection is better because the polyfill will not be 
                loaded, parsed and executed if it's not necessary.
            */
            {
                require: 'intersection-observer',
                detect: () => 'IntersectionObserver' in window,
            },

            /*
                Feature with detect & install:

                Some polyfills require a installation step
                Hence you could supply a install function which accepts the require result
            */
            {
                require: 'smoothscroll-polyfill',

                // Detection found in source: https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll/blob/master/src/smoothscroll.js
                detect: () => 'scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style && window.__forceSmoothScrollPolyfill__ !== true,

                // Optional install function called client side after the package is required:
                install: (smoothscroll) => smoothscroll.polyfill()
            }
        ]
    },

    // Add it to the modules section:
    modules: [
        'nuxt-polyfill',
    ]
}
```

Disclaimer: I made it.

Comment: For anyone using this options, I needed enter a detect method (in my case for Array.from: `detect: () => !Array.from`) for it to work, otherwise it wasn't loaded at all I think, or it assumed the native implementation was there on the server side so it didn't include it on the client side.

Comment: @Lumocra Could you share your whole solution ? We cannot seem to be able to make it work for `Array.from`

Comment: @Lumocra @Scriptodude If you do not supply a detect function, the polyfill will always be included and ran. But keep in mind that this happens when the first plugins start to run. So you need to make sure you only use the polyfill in `default exported functions` of plugins, `computed properties` or `methods` of components, any `getter, mutation or action` of vuex stores, etc. You can't just use it in the global path of the script because it's not polyfilled at that time.

Comment: @Scriptodude In nuxt.config.js: `polyfill: { features: [ ..., { require: 'array-from', detect: () => !Array.from }, ... ] },`

Comment: But I still have to manually add each polyfill? It can't detect which are needed based on the features in my code?

Comment: @Oli Unfortunately that's not possible in a language which is as dynamic as JavaScript. Fortunately though, you only have to set this up once!

Comment: @Tim Can you share an example using nuxt-polyfill with a bundle from polyfill.io as a package and not a URL ???

Answer (score 0):

I am using `nuxt 2.x`, and the fix is quite simple, you just need to add transpile in `nuxt.config.js`

```
build: { transpile: ['vue-cli-plugin-apollo'] }
```