# How to use event-source-polyfill on Nuxt 2

Tags: nuxt.js

I want to use event-source-polyfill on Nuxt 2 for ie11 hot reload.

I found: [How to add a polyfill to nuxt 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452501/how-to-add-a-polyfill-to-nuxt-2-0) 
but my env can’t access to CDN so I need to use local polyfill, which is installed “npm install event-source-polyfill”.

I got some information about vendor option but it is deprecated on Nuxt v2 and relese note says “Use webpack4”. 
How do I it?

Thank to take your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

First,

```
yarn add --dev eventsource-polyfill
```

then, in nuxt.config.js, add:

```
extend(config, ctx) {
  if(ctx.idDev) {
    config.entry.push('eventsource-polyfill')
  }
}
```