# using babel-polyfill (and not polyfill.io) in nuxt

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, nuxt.js

I am building a static site with nuxt vuetify template and while it's awesome and provides so many configurations and setup already done for me, I am finding it really hard to enable my site running smoothly on Internet Explorer (11).

Since, the ES6 code needs be transpiled, I am trying to configure babel in my app, and this is my very first experience of configuring babel (so, please ignore my lack of knowledge in the domain). there are so many issues/questions on the internet, and I have tried almost all but in vain.

**TL;DR**, I am using Nuxt 2.x (and Webpack 4, internally), I do not have a clue where and how do I include the `@babel/polyfill` because,

1. we do not have a defined or explicit entry point in Nuxt app, where I could have imported that file `import '@babel.polyfill'`, as stated in a number of places, including babel official documentation
2. webpack 4 doesn't have an `entry.vendor` field either, where I could have injected that polyfill.

here is my **nuxt.config.js**:

```
babel: {
      presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', {
          'useBuiltIns': 'usage',
          'targets': '> 0.25%, not dead'
        }]
      ],
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import', [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        {
          'corejs': false,
          'helpers': true,
          'regenerator': true,
          'useESModules': false
        }
      ]],
      'configFile': false,
      'babelrc': false
}
```

here are the versions of packages I am using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5"
}

"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.3.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.2.0"
}
```

following [this thread](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/509#issuecomment-291799186), I also thought to push `babel polyfill` as a vendor to webpack entry object but it gives me the error: `Cannot set property 'vendor' of undefined` because, apparently, webpack 4 configs doesn't have an entry field, just like webpack 3 used to have.

this is my **webapack config:**

```
{ 
  name: 'client',                                                                                                                                                                                 
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: false,
  optimization: 
   { runtimeChunk: 'single',
     minimize: true,
     minimizer: undefined,
     splitChunks: 
      { chunks: 'all',
        automaticNameDelimiter: '.',
        name: undefined,
        cacheGroups: [Object] } },
  output: 
   { path: '/home/waleed/project/.nuxt/dist/client',
     filename: '[chunkhash].js',
     chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js',
     publicPath: '/_nuxt/' },
  performance: { maxEntrypointSize: 1024000, hints: 'warning' },
  resolve: 
   { extensions: [ '.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.vue', '.jsx' ],
     alias: 
      { '~': '/home/waleed/project',
        '~~': '/home/waleed/project',
        '@': '/home/waleed/project',
        '@@': '/home/waleed/project',
        assets: '/home/waleed/project/assets',
        static: '/home/waleed/project/static' },
     modules: 
      [ 'node_modules',
        '/home/waleed/projectnode_modules',
        '/home/waleed/project/node_modules/@nuxt/config/node_modules' ] },
  resolveLoader: 
   { modules: 
      [ 'node_modules',
        '/home/waleed/project/node_modules',
        '/home/waleed/project/node_modules/@nuxt/config/node_modules' ] },
  module: 
   { rules: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  plugins: 
   [ VueLoaderPlugin {},
     WarnFixPlugin {},
     WebpackBarPlugin {
       profile: false,
       handler: [Function],
       modulesCount: 500,
       showEntries: false,
       showModules: true,
       showActiveModules: true,
       options: [Object],
       reporters: [Array] },
     MiniCssExtractPlugin { options: [Object] },
     HtmlWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] },
     HtmlWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] },
     VueSSRClientPlugin { options: [Object] },
     DefinePlugin { definitions: [Object] } ] 
}
```

P.S: I have already seen and tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452501/how-to-add-a-polyfill-to-nuxt-2-0), and it surely have somewhat worked too, but my use case demands **not to use** polyfill.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all those, banging their heads like me, (as a temporary solution) I decided to go with babel-polyfill [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-polyfill) and included its url in scripts section of `nuxt.config.js` file, as under

```
script: [
      { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.2.5/polyfill.min.js' }
    ]
```

However, I am still looking for a cleaner and more ES6ish `import` or `require` syntax for achieving the required results. So, please feel free to add more answers if you have one such solution.

Comment: I tried same but got SCRIPT1002: Syntax error at vendors.app.js (7694,1)