# When and How to add polyfills to a vue-cli app

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have a `vue-cli 3` app created, and seeing some error messages logged about some JS methods not existing in some browsers.

One error is that `AbortController` is not defined.

My questions are:

1. Was my assumption correct that the default `vue-cli` webpack configuration would  add polyfills for these features, such as `fetch`, or `const` keywords?
2. Assuming there are some features which aren't polyfilled by default, how can I add a specific one, like `AbortController` or `fetch`?

```
                    **.browserslistrc**
> 1%
last 2 versions
not ie <= 8
```

```
                    **vue.config.js**
module.exports = {
    pwa: {...}
}
```

Comment: The [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#polyfills) go over how they suggest adding polyfills.

Comment: You may find the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452501) helpful.

Comment: For myself, I had to add `transpileDependencies` option in `vue.config.js` for a dependency I was using as per the link by @StevenB.