# Object.entries is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Lately, a lot of errors have started to come up, referring to this:

```
Object.entries is not a function
```

This piece of code is used in several places in Vue components.

There is also a `.browserslistrc` file:

```
defaults
```

Recently, this error began to come from devices running iOS 10.1 (Facebook 68.0.0). Until then, it was only found on Andrioid <6. And now all this began to strain a lot.

Tell me, please, how can I fix this situation? Maybe something needs to be written in the `.browserslistrc` file? Or something else? There are no other similar issues in JS.

Comment: [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility) is supported from safari on iOS 10.3, at least from what i am reading. You should probably move down to ES6, polyfill it, ...

Comment: @ASDFGerte Can this be fixed somehow? At the same time for Android <6 too.

Comment: Tons of ways, i don't have too much experience in doing this though, as i hardly ever have to cater to older versions (lucky me!). As said, downemit to ES6 (e.g. with babel, or if you use typescript anyways, then configure tsc, ...), add a polyfill for the function (if it's only that one, and not a bunch of other ES2017+ functions aswell), ...

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452501).

Comment: @ASDFGerte It seems to me that I have a normal config and I need to fix one, the minimum. It has CoreJS. I'm afraid to break it. Can you please tell me? https://pastebin.com/raw/tZrx4MRg

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the devices/browsers you mentioned don't support `Object.entries`. To support environments that do not natively support Object.entires, make sure that in the polyfill section of your `babel.config.js` file, you add `es7.object.entries`. If you see `es6.object` in this section, remove it.

Example:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@vue/app",
      {
        polyfills: ["es7.object.entries"]
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

Comment: What if I don't have `@vue/app`? I just have a config built based on Webpacker (https://pastebin.com/raw/tZrx4MRg).

Comment: After looking at your config file, I believe this plugin will solve your problem. DISCLAIMER: I haven't ever had to use it. But you should be able to add it to the section with the rest of your plugins. Plugin name: "transform-es2017-object-entries"  https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2017-object-entries